# Getting JSON from nodejs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

So I couldn't find my answer anywhere. Using node I got everything from database, and I outputted it into the file. It's simple JSON data, chat logs. I can access it though my browser. Looks like this:

```
[{
  "id":"1b4f0d8b-4577-493e-adde 68a9a96f647d",
  "message":"Hi",
  "name":"NilmeX",
  "timestamp":"18:11"
},
{
  "id":"4b4f2dc1-7162-484b-98b4-dbdbc751dff4",
  "message":"Hi2",
  "name":"NilmeX",
  "timestamp":"18:11"
}]
```

Etc..

Now how can I get this data by angular? I tried `$http.get` but I think I messed something up... I'm new to angular and node, so if someone can explain it to me I will be happy.

Comment: can you post your try with `$http.get` and we can figure it out

Comment: @Abdoutelb   `$http.get("/logs/chat")
      .then(function(response) {
          $scope.msgs = response.data;
      });`

Comment: This url is invalid , you can try put the working url in the browser if it return the right data put it inside `$http.get`

Comment: @Abdoutelb Im getting `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` all the time. Weird

Comment: Are you injecting `$http` in your controller ?

Comment: @Abdoutelb Oh damn, I was, but only in function... Stupid mistake. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 


<p ng-repeat="item in myArray">{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</p>



</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("service endpoint from nodejs")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myArray = response.data;
    });
});
</script>
```